# Order By not working with Top MS SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sorting, datatable

I'm creating a query that should fit with the DataTable I'm working on from MsSQL. This is my first time to work on MsSQL so I'm trying to figure out the equivalent MsSQL query from my MySQL.

I made a custom query that will handle the `LIMIT` function in MySQL to MsSQL(hopefully). I have the following query that I use in my datatable:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT top 20 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
        AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
        FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
        WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
        AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
        AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
        AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
        GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
        ORDER BY CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) ASC
    ) as foo
    except
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT top 10 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
        AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
        FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
        WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
        AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
        AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
        AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
        GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
        ORDER BY CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) ASC
    ) as bar
```

The result is:

```
week_name     | Average_Delivery_Days
==================================
2017 Week 36  | 15
2017 Week 39  | 11
2017 Week 41  | 13
2017 Week 42  | 10
2017 Week 38  | 12
2017 Week 40  | 12
2017 Week 35  | 14
2017 Week 43  | 6
2017 Week 37  | 12
2017 Week 44  | 9
```

But I would like it to be sorted by week number ascending so it should display 36, 37, 38, 39, and so on.

What could be missing in my query?

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar situation, I finally got the right query:

```
SELECT 
/* Explicitly select these columns */
week_name, Average_Delivery_Days, delivery_date_year, delivery_date_week
FROM (
SELECT top 20
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as delivery_date_year, DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) as delivery_date_week,
AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
ORDER BY delivery_date_year ASC, delivery_date_week ASC
) as foo
EXCEPT
SELECT week_name, Average_Delivery_Days, delivery_date_year, delivery_date_week
FROM (
SELECT top 10
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as delivery_date_year, DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) as delivery_date_week,
AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
ORDER BY delivery_date_year ASC, delivery_date_week ASC
) as bar ORDER BY delivery_date_week, delivery_date_year
```

Answer (score 6):

Your ORDER BY clause only affects the TOP selection; it doesn't order the result set.  Adding an ORDER BY to the end of the query should do the trick.

I do see one other issue, however, which is that you're going to be sorting a VARCHAR column with numbers in it.  VARCHAR is sorted alphabetically, so Week 2 will appear after Week 19.  So I would do this:

```
SELECT 
/* Explicitly select these columns */
week_name
, Average_Delivery_Days


FROM (
    SELECT top 20
    /* Add separate columns for numerical year and week */
     iyear = YEAR(DeliveryDate)
    , iweek = DATEPART(WEEK,DeliveryDate)
    , CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
    FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
    WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
    AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
    AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
    AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
    ORDER BY CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) ASC
) as foo
except
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT top 10 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name, 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days
    FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
    WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
    AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
    AND [RouteID] IS NOT NULL AND [RouteID] != '' AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
    AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) >= DATEADD(week, -24, getdate()) 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) 
    ORDER BY CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) ASC
) as bar
 /* sort by the numeric columns */
 ORDER BY foo.iyear, foo.iweek
```

Comment: Hi Dave! Thanks for your answer. However, I got this error: `Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.`